# Если 2 человека одновременно обратятся к main.php

Tags: php

Если 2 человека одновременно обратятся к main.php, работа которого сравнима с покупкой последнего билета, (т.е. забрать может только один) то что будет?

Задачи в PHP на сервере выполняются по очереди или одновременно?

Comment: смотря где у вас хранятся билеты и как устроен файл main. Может получиться, что будут проданы 2 билета, а может второму выведется сообщение, что билетов нет

Comment: Обычно, задачи на web сервере выполняются одновременно (параллельно) за счёт возможности веб сервера (например Apache или Nginx) принимать параллельные подключения. Другими словами, при каждом обращении пользователя, веб сервер попросит PHP исполнить main.php

Comment: Предположим, что main.php отсылает клиенту ключ-пароль из бд alert'ом, а затем удаляет его из бд. 
Что будет, если сразу 2 пользователя одновременно запустят main.php?

Ситуация 1
Обоим придёт этот ключ.
Ситуация 2.
Выведет кому-то из них что ключи закончились.

Comment: Используйте эксклюзивную блокировку ( БД если используется - SELECT ... FOR UPDATE,  или на файле - flock() ) в месте, где вы изменяете данные.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, Вам стоит ознакомиться с частью документации по SQL об уровнях изолирования транзакций (TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL). Поскольку Вы не конкретизировали СУБД, с которой гипотетически будет спариваться гипотетически параллельно выполняемый скрипт `main.php`, даю Вам ссылку на [википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9). В Вашем случае

> Предположим, что main.php отсылает клиенту ключ-пароль из бд alert'ом, а затем удаляет его из бд. Что будет, если сразу 2 пользователя одновременно запустят main.php? Ситуация 1 Обоим придёт этот ключ. Ситуация 2. Выведет кому-то из них что ключи закончились.

для предотвращения первого (неблагоприятного) исхода следует воспользоваться уровнем изоляции `SERIALIZABLE` для выполнения всех транзакций, связанных с "ключ-паролями". Но, поскольку этот уровень изоляции слишком "нагибает" базу в сфере быстродействия, для других операций, не требующих такого уровня безопасности, продолжать пользоваться уровнем изоляции `REPEATABLE READ` (обычно стоит по умолчанию в реляционных СУБД).

Так что, если Вы используете необходимый уровень изоляции транзакций, - Ваш "сферический конь в вакууме" подковы не потеряет и лишнюю ногу не приобретет. :)

**Update**

Действительно, затупил. Как верно заметил @Jigius в своем комментарии к вопросу, использование `SELECT FOR UPDATE` при `REPEATABLE READ` гарантирует блокировку чтения на время выполнения обновления. Более подробно - [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935850/when-to-use-select-for-update).